# Data Corruption Bug in flash.filesystem.FileStream or Developer Error?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I was implementing some data structure backed by a file and used random read and write access to update the structure.

And stumbled over either a bad bug or my code is not correct.

After hours of checking and debugging it boiled down to the following snippet, that isolates the erroneous? behavior.

Inside the loop i am supposedly writing, reading and overwriting the byte at position 0.
You would expect, after the code has run, to end up with a file containing 1 byte `0x39`.
Instead the file grows, the writing is not happening at position 0 but at EOF. Runnig the code several times will result in the file growing larger and larger.

If you comment the line `fs.readByte();` out, the code is behaving as expected.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;

var tf:File=File.userDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();

fs.open(tf,FileMode.UPDATE);

for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
   fs.position=0;
   fs.writeByte(0x30+i);
   fs.position=0;
   fs.readByte(); //if you comment this line out, results are as expected
}

fs.close();
trace(tf.size);
```

Please, if anybody is testing this and come to the same conclusion as me, that this is
a bug, please vote this bug at adobe's bugbase, so they hopefully consider fixing it.

[VOTE BUG at ADOBE's bugbase](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3498173)!

Otherwise I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrongly.

tx leo

EDIT: some clarification

```
//Alright, since the loop example caused some confusion about whether or not
//there would be use for such code I'll try with another snippet, that is hopefully
//closer to some real application.
//
//The code updates some bytes in the file 
//and afterwards reads some bytes somewhere else in the file, eg. a header field.
//This time not in a loop but triggered by a timer, which could of course also
//be some event handler.
//
//I hope this makes the problem more apparent

import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;   


var tf=File.userDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();
var timerID:int;
var count:int=0;

var fileAction:Function=function(){
    var dataToWrite:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
    var dataToRead:ByteArray=new ByteArray();

    dataToWrite[0]=0x31;
    dataToWrite[1]=0x32;

    fs.position=2;
    fs.writeBytes(dataToWrite);
    fs.position=0;
    fs.readBytes(dataToRead,0,2);  //this read will corrupt the previous write!!!
                                   //instead updating two bytes at 0x02 
                                   //it will write to the end of file,
                                   //appending two bytes
    count++;
    if (count>10) {
        clearInterval(timerID);
        fs.close();
        trace("Excpected file size: 4")
        trace("Actual size: "+tf.size);

    }

}

fs.open(tf,FileMode.UPDATE);
fs.position=0;
fs.writeByte(0x30);
fs.writeByte(0x30);

timerID=setInterval(fileAction,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that your expectations are founded based on the documentation, I'm not sure what use it is to read what was just written, especially within a loop on a `FileStream` object, as it is an unnecessarily performance hit.  Can you provide a usecase?

Perhaps there are undocumented restrictions within the `FileStream` API that avoid excessive slow downs or that impede synchronous or asynchronous processing.

If you must read a byte after it's been written within a loop, you can do so with a `ByteArray` object, which would then be written once to the `FileStream`

```
package 
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    //Class
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        //Constructor
        public function Main():void 
        {
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
               ba.position = 0;
               ba.writeByte(0x30 + i);
               ba.position = 0;
               ba.readByte();
            }

            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            var tf:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");

            fs.open(tf, FileMode.UPDATE);
            fs.writeBytes(ba);
            fs.close();

            trace(tf.size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code snippet does not do anything except exposing the bug, no real use. The problem is rather the fact that **a READ breaks a previous WRITE**, which is a serious error and leads to data corruption. Also I don't think it matters if you read the data that was written or any other data.

Comment: please see the EDIT in the original question for a better code example